# InvalidOpertationExecution was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

When I run my app, I get this error:

**InvalidOperationException: The 'Id' property on 'SiteTable' could not be set to a 'Double' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Int32'.**

The code that produces this:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetSites()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> sitesDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    var sites = from r in _db.SITE
                orderby r.Name
                select r;

    foreach (var site in sites)
    {
        sitesDict.Add(site.Id.ToString(), site.Name);
    }
    return sitesDict;
}
```

While in debugger, the error dialog points to the foreach loop and `in` is highlighted green.

This error only occurs run time.

The stack trace:

```
System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal) +292
System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetPropertyValueWithErrorHandling(Int32 ordinal, String propertyName, String typeName) +51
lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +97
System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly(Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet) +218
lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +291
System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper) +170
System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext() +84
ARFODataService.SearchServices.ARFOStaticValues.GetSites() in <snip>\ARFODataService\SearchServices\ARFOStaticValues.cs:22
ARFO_Stewardship.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in <snip>\ARFO_Stewardship\Controllers\HomeController.cs:31
lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +96
System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +208
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +55
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +19
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8963149
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

Appreciate any help with figuring this out.

Thanks.

Comment: This exception is likely produceed in your _db class when materializing a site. There is no relation with MVC3. Looking at the errormessage, I can assume that you have a mapping problem. Please post the mapping logic

Comment: The error message is self explanatory and tells you exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first commenter is correct, from the error message it looks like your database is saying the value "SiteTable.ID" is an int but your entity object thinks that it is a double (or maybe it's the other way around).

Try refreshing your entity object against the database.

Comment: Simon, thanks. Every single one of my mappings was wrong. How can that happen? We dropped the DB and recreated it but everything was named the same way. But ok, I can work with this. Thanks.

Comment: I actually had some like this the other day, is your model created from a database or vice versa?